# How to put different digits in different sides

Tags: c

How to write a program in c that gets single integer and another integer that is more than 3 digits at least and after that the single integer goes to the left  side of the three digits number and the right side as well.

Note: I need help for the left side right side number

For example:

I mean if I got 5 and 100
it should be 51005

Comment: `int a = 5, b = 100; printf("%d%d%d\n", a, b, a);`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are so many methods :
one is stated in the reply above by @MikeCAT .

```
int a = 5, b = 100; printf("%d%d%d\n", a, b, a);
```

you can also try to transfer them to strings , contact them and put it back as an int if you're asked to have a variable named as c using [itoa](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-type-casting/c-itoa-function/)   and [atoi](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) with a very static manner

```
char string[100],string1[100],string2[210];
int a,b,c;
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
itoa(a,string,10);
itoa(b,string1,10);
string2 = string+string1+string;
c=atoi(string2);
printf("Your number %d",c);
```

you can also try to think about it mathematically

```
int a,b;
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
int x=b,i=0,c=a;
while (x!=0) { // to get the length of b
i++;
x= x/10; }
int j ;
for (j=1;j<i;j++)
c=c*10;
c=c+b+a;
printf("your number is %d",c);
```

etc etc

Comment: can you please continue it ?

Comment: @LiorPav i gave you the road , you should try coding then tell us if you're good .

Comment: how does the length of the number helps me ?

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
  int a = 5, b = 100;

  int length = 1;

  int tmp = b;
  while (tmp /= 10)
      length++;
 
  int left = 10;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    left *= 10;


  int result = (left * a) + (10 * b) + a;

  std::cout << result;
```

Also, you can play [here.](https://onlinegdb.com/H177QYSDd)